# .env file in main.py

Tags: python, dotenv

I have

```
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), verbose=True)
```

in my main.py file. The load_dotenv returns True. Then later in the file I am using some class methods imported from other files. These methods use environmental variables in my .env file. I'm confused about one thing. When I debug, I can access variables by:

```
os.getenv('API_KEY')
```

But when I do say

```
print(os.getenv('API_KEY'))
```

from other .py files than main.py, it says None. What's going on here?

OK, I have isolated what's happening, here is a.py file which has a class I'm calling from main.py

```
#This doesn't work
print(os.getenv('API_KEY'))

class C():
    def: met():
        #This works
        print(os.getenv('API_KEY'))
```

Not sure I know why this happens ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's a minimal example that I expect shows the behavior you're experiencing:

```py
# ./main.py
from dotenv import load_dotenv, find_dotenv
import os

import helper  # executes all the code in helper.py, below


load_dotenv(find_dotenv(), verbose=True)  # loads the .env file into the environment

print(os.getenv('API_KEY'))  # WORKS!
foo = helper.SomeClass().print_env()  # also works!
```

```
# ./helper.py
import os


print(os.getenv('API_KEY'))  # FAILS!

class SomeClass():
    def print_env():
        print(os.getenv('API_KEY'))
```

This makes sense because of that comment on `import helper`. When you import a python module, it executes all the code *in* that module *right then.* Since you're running the import before you run `load_dotenv`, the environment hasn't been loaded with the key you expect. However, when you put the call into a class, then by the time you instantiate the class the environment has already been populated.

Comment: Ah, I'll test. It makes perfect sense though. I also know about this but I guess my brain just stopped working haha. Thanks!